# Format C code with prettier vscode: disable single space between ) { brackets?

Tags: vscode-extensions, prettier

So I've setup the Prettier extension in VSCode so far to format the file like this with LLVM Mode but there's still one thing I want to config which annoys me a bit and that is the space between brackets it puts example:

```c
void LEDThread() {
  int C = 0;
  while (1) {
    tx_thread_sleep(200);
    C++;
    printf("Blink transition count: %d\n", C);
  }
}
```

in `void LEDThread() {` line I want it to not generate this space between the ) and { braces,

how would one do that?

I've searched in hte [official docs here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) but couldn't find anything that refers to the space at hand.

I've searched in hte [official docs here](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html) but couldn't find anything that refers to the space at hand.